# ngProgress loading bar on every page load

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS and [ngProgress](http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/) to display a YouTube-like loading bar at the top of my site.

The bar is started, then new data is loaded in via ajax, and once the request is finished, the bar is completed.

Example:

```
var TestCtrl = function( $scope, $location, Tests, ngProgress ) 
{
    // start progressbar
    ngProgress.start();

    $scope.tests = Tests.query(
        function()
        {
            // end progressbar
            ngProgress.complete()
        }
    );
};
```

Now my question is: How can I integrate this principle higher up in the order of things, such that I don't have to repeat the code for every single controller?

Comment: Throw it in a service, and inject the service into every controller that needs its functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a service which controls ngProgress (acting like a wrapper over it) and listen for changes in the url.

- Each time the url changes the event `$locationChangeSuccess` is broadcasted (more info at [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location)) which we could listen to invoke `ngProgress.start()`
- However we don't know when it's completed (we can't have a bar on the top loading forever), therefore we need to call `ngProgress.complete()` explicitly in our controllers OR we could assume that our async functions might take like 5 seconds to be completed and call `ngProgress.complete()` using a timer in our wrapper service
- When the loading bar is already visible and there's a change in the url we need to reset the status of the bar by calling `ngProgress.reset()`

You can use the following approach to solve these problems:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Progress', function (ngProgress) {
    var timer;
    return {
        start: function () {
            var me = this;
            // reset the status of the progress bar
            me.reset();
            // if the `complete` method is not called
            // complete the progress of the bar after 5 seconds
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                me.complete();
            }, 5000);
        },
        complete: function () {
            ngProgress.complete();
            if (timer) {
                // remove the 5 second timer
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = null;
            }
        },
        reset: function () {             
            if (timer) {
                // remove the 5 second timer
                clearTimeout(timer);
                // reset the progress bar
                ngProgress.reset();
            }
            // start the progress bar
            ngProgress.start();
        }
    };
});
```

To listen for changes in the url and show the progress bar we could use:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .run(function (Progress) {
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
            Progress.start();
        });
    }
```

Now we can manually control the completeness of the status bar by injecting the `Progress` service and calling the method `Progress.complete()` when all of our async functions have finished (we could also control this from any service that makes async calls):

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('SomeCtrl', function (Progress) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            Progress.complete();
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using Interceptor:

```
.factory('interceptorNgProgress', [
    'ngProgressFactory', function (ngProgressFactory) {

var complete_progress, getNgProgress, ng_progress, working;
ng_progress = null;
working = false;

getNgProgress = function() {

    if(!ng_progress) {

        ng_progress = ngProgressFactory.createInstance();

        return ng_progress;
    }

    return ng_progress;
};

complete_progress = function() {
    var ngProgress;
    if (working) {
        ngProgress = getNgProgress();
        ngProgress.complete();
        return working = false;
    }
};

return {
    request: function(request) {
        var ngProgress;
        ngProgress = getNgProgress();
        if (request.url.indexOf('.html') > 0) {
            return request;
        }
        if (!working) {
            ngProgress.reset();
            ngProgress.start();
            working = true;
        }
        return request;
    },
    requestError: function(request) {
        complete_progress();
        return request;
    },
    response: function(response) {
        complete_progress();
        return response;
    },
    responseError: function(response) {
        complete_progress();
        return response;
    }
}
}])

.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('interceptorNgProgress');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Zeecher for this. It really worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in an angular directive and then you can pass that into any controller you want to be able to use it.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Edit, thinking about it a service mght be better for this case.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services

Answer (score 0):

You apparently already have a `Tests` service. Override it so `ngProgress` is injected into it and have `Tests` always call `ngProgress.start()` and `ngProgress.complete()` for you in `query`.